# How to pass the validator property to a h:inputText from a JSF2 composite component?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, validation, composite-component

We have a text input component created as a JSF 2 component that encapsulates both the label and the edit field (`h:inputText`), and which also takes care of the layout.
Our problem at the moment is to get the validator property of the inputField to be exposed on our composite component. We have the attribute declared on the cc:interface section, but the problem in adding a `validator="#{validator}"` when declaring the inner h:inputText in the cc:implementation is that when the field is not used it fails during runtime.

I wanted to do this in the same way it is done for h:inputText, without having to register a custom validator.

Is there some known solution for this type of problem? We tried to create a custom tag to be used inside the composite component, but it was over complex and it didn't worked at the end, so I thought in asking to the experts if there is an easy way of doing this.

**Note: I want to use a method-binding expression in the validator property of my composite component, just as the original of the h:inputText.**
Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a few components with specific masks, validations and converters.

First, I defined a component called 'defaultText' like this:

```
</cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value"/>
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="mycomp" targets="input"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <p:inputMask id="input" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"/>
</cc:implementation>
```

(there are some other attributes I'm letting out to save space). See the editableValueHandler? it's where you define to what component you will link your conversor/validator.

So, I used my 'defaultText' component to build other components, for example, 'text.xhtml':

```
</cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value"/>
    <cc:attribute name="mask"/>
    <cc:attribute name="jsfConverter"/>
    <cc:attribute name="jsfValidator"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <foo:defaultText id="dt" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" mask="#{cc.attrs.mask}">
        <c:if test="#{!empty cc.attrs.jsfConverter}">
            <f:converter converterId="#{cc.attrs.jsfConverter}" for="mycomp"/>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="#{!empty cc.attrs.jsfValidator}">
            <f:validator validatorId="#{cc.attrs.jsfValidator}" for="mycomp"/>
        </c:if>
    </foo:defaultText>
</cc:implementation>
```

The `<composite:editableValueHolder>` define that any validator/converter (`<f:validator for="mycomp">`) will be associated to `<p:inputMask id="input">`.

Then I use my text component on my pages:

```
<foo:text value="#{dummyMBean.text}" mask="99.999-99" jsfConverter="..." jsfValidator="..."/>
```